# Pythonic way to get polars data frame absolute max values of all relevant columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars

I want to create absolute maximum of all Polars data frame columns. Here is a way, but surely could be improved.

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two"],
    "val1": [1.2, -2.3, 3, -3.3, 2.2, -1.3],
    "val2": [1,2,3,-4,-3,-2]
    })

absVals = []
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        absVals.append((lambda arr: max(arr.min(), arr.max(), key=abs)) (df[col]))
    except:
        absVals.append(np.NaN)

df_out= pl.DataFrame(data=absVals).transpose()
df_out.columns=df.columns
print(df_out)
```

Outputs -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two"],
    "val1": [1.2, -2.3, 3, -3.3, 2.2, -1.3],
    "val2": [1,2,3,-4,-3,-2]
    })
```

[polars.DataFrame.schema](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.schema.html#polars.DataFrame.schema)

schema has the Column name as well as the Column datatype.

`pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES` contains all the numeric datatypes.

```
for col,typ in df.schema.items():
    if typ in pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES:
        print(max(df[col],key=abs))
    else:
        print(np.NaN)
```

Using List comprehension in one line:

```
[max(df[col],key=abs) if typ in pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES else np.NaN for col,typ in df.schema.items()]

output
#[nan, -3.3, -4]
```

---

Bonus:

Your code without lambda:

```
lst=[]
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        lst.append(max(df[col],key=abs))
    except:
        lst.append(np.NaN)

print(lst)
[nan, -3.3, -4]
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `max(..., key=abs)` is essentially doing a [`.sort_by()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.sort_by.html#polars.Expr.sort_by)

```py
floats = pl.all().cast(float, strict=False)

df.select(floats.sort_by(floats.abs()).last())
```

```py
shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ name ┆ val1 ┆ val2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ -3.3 ┆ -4.0 │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

You can `.fill_null(float("nan"))` if you want `NaN` in there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you really want the max(absolute value) as the question implies or the value from the DF which gives that max as your result shows. If the former then:

```
df.select(pl.col(['val1', 'val2']).map_batches(lambda x: max(abs(x))))
```

gives:

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ val1 ┆ val2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 3.3  ┆ 4    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

or for the latter as clarified by the OP in the comment:

```
df.select(pl.col(['val1', 'val2']).map_batches(lambda x: max(x.min(), x.max(), key=abs)))
```

which gives
shape: (1, 2)

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│ val1 ┆ val2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ -3.3 ┆ -4   │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wanted the max(absolute value) with sign remain intact. So, this will work - df.select(pl.col(['val1', 'val2']).map_batches(lambda arr: max(arr.min(), arr.max(), key=abs)))

Answer (score 1):

This also works if you don't care about non-numeric columns, even though a bit uglier that I would've liked:

```
import polars.selectors as cs

df.select(
    pl.when(
        cs.numeric() == (cs.numeric().abs().max() * cs.numeric().sign())
    )
    .then(
        cs.numeric()
    )
).max()
```

It finds all the rows in numeric columns where the value is equal to max absolute value multiplied by it's sign (-1,1 or 0). Every other row value is assigned null because of the `when...then`, so applying `max()` again gets the non-null values.